# Using a specific RGB color to create an image

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

For a project we had to create a 14x14 matrix from a 7 digit number and then convert it to an image (140 pixels by 140 pixels) whose base color would be defined by the last digit of the previously mentioned number.

Now, I have done everything but the examples given have a black to color gradient and my images are coming out with a white to color gradient.

Example given: https://ibb.co/FbvXdXb

My image: https://ibb.co/zZVHCMG

I'm using this to create the image and the cmap:

`plt.set_cmap('Purples')`

`plt.imsave('test.png', array)`

How can I make my image look like the example one?

Any help is appreciated!

The colors we must choose from are mentioned in their RGB representation i.e. R 255, G 255, B 0 for Yellow.

So, I'm guessing I have to use those values to color the image but I can't with set_cmap and can't find what I should use.

Code in use:

(please remember that I just started learning python lol)

```
from random import randint
import re
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors

rStudentNum = "r0914826"
rNum = re.sub('r', '', rStudentNum)
numCounter = 0

def IsEven(num):
    isEven = bool
    if int(num[3]) % 2 == 0:
        isEven = True
        return isEven
    else:
        isEven = False
        return isEven

def GetRandomNum():
    randomNum = randint(0,13)
    return randomNum

studentMatrix = np.arange(0,196,1)
studentMatrix = studentMatrix.reshape(14,14)

if IsEven(rNum) == True:
    for i in range(1,14,2):
        usingNum = int(rNum[numCounter])        
        print(usingNum)
        studentMatrix[i]
        randomNum = GetRandomNum()
        lineCounter = 0
        while randomNum + usingNum > 14:
            randomNum = GetRandomNum()
        
        for x in range(0, usingNum):            
            studentMatrix[i][randomNum + lineCounter] = usingNum
            lineCounter += 1
        
        if numCounter < len(rNum) - 1:
            if i % 2 != 0 or i == 1:
                numCounter += 1    
else:
    for i in range(0,14,2):
        usingNum = int(rNum[numCounter])        
        print(usingNum)
        studentMatrix[i]
        randomNum = GetRandomNum()
        lineCounter = 0
        while randomNum + usingNum > 14:
            randomNum = GetRandomNum()
        
        for x in range(0, usingNum):            
            studentMatrix[i][randomNum + lineCounter] = usingNum
            lineCounter += 1
        
        if numCounter < len(rNum) - 1:
            if i % 2 == 0 or i == 0:
                numCounter += 1

studentMatrix = studentMatrix.transpose()
print(studentMatrix)

cmap = mcolors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(['black', mcolors.from_rgb(255,255,0)])
plt.set_cmap(cmap)
plt.imsave(f'{rStudentNum}.png', studentMatrix)
```

Comment: Thanks @JohanC! I'll try that. I apologize for the reproducible code and test data, I'll keep it in mind for next post!

Comment: @JohanC added the reproducible code. I can't seem to find 'from_rgb' in the mcolors documentation though.

Comment: It seems the internal format is already in rbg, but as values between 0 and 1. So  `cmap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('', ['black', (r / 255, g / 255, b / 255)])` if r, g and be are integers between 0 and 255.

Comment: @JohanC worked perfectly! Can I accept your answer from here?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
plt.set_cmap('Purples')
```

Use

```
plt.set_cmap('Purples_r')
```

Comment: This just reversed the gradient though.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).